# tinyMCE Editor Margins on tinyMCE container

Tags: css, tinymce, margins

This may be a stupid question but how do i add a margin to the bottom of the tinyMCE editor. I have a margin on the bottom of the textarea I am targeting with tinyMCE but i assume it is being replaced with the editor and my styling on the textarea is moot. I opened the css files for the advanced theme but I can't seem to find what tag needs the margin added to it.

The answer to this is probably staring me in the face. But its just one of those programming days. I can't burn up anymore hours trying to figure this out I'm moving on but if anyone has any insight that would kick ass.

thanks,

-L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just applied the following to the "full featured example" on the TinyMCE website via Firebug, it worked nicely. The `textarea` element is indeed replaced, though you might choose to add margin to the bottom of that too - for when TinyMCE hasn't replaced the element yet, to avoid jumping layout.

```
table.mceLayout { margin-bottom:100px; }
```

Comment: Perfect. You're a life saver. Simple but just one of those things. Thanks

Comment: Heh heh, I know what you mean, no probs :P